# How to show value in input field with ng-model?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-1.6

I created edit form so I have to include default value for each text field. I wrote this HTML code:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="projectData.title" ng-init="projectData.title=title" name="title" class="form-control" />
```

In controller:

```
$scope.title = "This is just title";
```

It shows nothing in the text box. I tried `ng-init="projectData.title={{title}}"` and `ng-init="projectData.title='title'"` but it's just not working.

I'm using angularjs 1.6 and the following solution is not working too.

http://jsfiddle.net/Aejvm/337/

Comment: Your fiddle is different than what you are asking.

Comment: you need `$scope.projectData.title` instead of `$scope.title`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your scope, you should declare the object like so:

```
$scope.projectData = {};
$scope.projectData.title = "This is just title";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Check This [Code][1]
  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/d4ts76ys/
```

Use the object to map it to ng-model

Answer (score 0):

Well you are doing a little wrong.

ng-init is angular directive and you dont need curly braces.

modify your code to this :
 html:

```
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-init="rootFolders.name=name" ng- 
    model="rootFolders.name"  >
 <br>rootFolders={{name}}
   </div>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
 app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) { 
   $scope.name = "Acunisasi";
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I have created fiddle that may help your
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arvindpal/jh6fr9dp/607/)

```
//html
<div ng-controller='MyCtrl'>
  <form>
    <input ng-init="projectData.title = title" type="text" ng-model="title">
        <button ng-click="formSubmit()">
        submit
        </button>
  </form>
  {{title}}
</div>

//js

 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', MyController]);

 function MyController($scope) {
   $scope.projectData = {};
   $scope.title = 'This is just title';

   $scope.formSubmit = function() {
     console.log("$scope.projectData  ===>", $scope.projectData)
   }
 }
```